# WebdriverIO throws ETIMEDOUT error in spite of setting up the proxy

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, automation, webdriver-io

We are using webdriverIO with typescript and we have setup the proxy correctly.
it throws the error: **connect FETCHError ETIMEDOUT**.

The timeout error occurs while downloading edge driver, connecting to lambdatest or saucelabs devices.
We tried adding the proxy using the below

set HTTP_PROXY= http://proxy.host.blah:80
set HTTPS_PROXY= http://proxy.host.blah:80

Also we tried setting up the proxy with
https://webdriver.io/docs/proxy/

Our IT team says, the proxy is set correctly but the webdriverIO is not using the proxy for sending the requests to the server.Looking forward to have solution which can direct webdriverIO to use proxy for all the server calls.

**Find the complete console log below-**

FetchError: FetchError: request to https://msedgedriver.azureedge.net/118.0.2088.69/edgedriver_win64.zip failed, reason: connect ETIMEDOUT 13.107.213.41:443
at ClientRequest. (file:///C:/.. /node_modules/node-fetch/src/index.js:108:11)
at ClientRequest.emit (node:events:512:28)
at ClientRequest.emit (node:domain:489:12)
at TLSSocket.socketErrorListener (node:_http_client:496:9)
at TLSSocket.emit (node:events:512:28)
at TLSSocket.emit (node:domain:489:12)
at emitErrorNT (node:internal/streams/destroy:151:8)
at emitErrorCloseNT (node:internal/streams/destroy:116:3)
at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:82:21)
FetchError: request to https://msedgedriver.azureedge.net/118.0.2088.69/edgedriver_win64.zip failed, reason: connect ETIMEDOUT 13.107.213.41:443
at ClientRequest. (file:///C:/.. /node_modules/node-fetch/src/index.js:108:11)
at ClientRequest.emit (node:events:512:28)
at ClientRequest.emit (node:domain:489:12)
at TLSSocket.socketErrorListener (node:_http_client:496:9)
at TLSSocket.emit (node:events:512:28)
at TLSSocket.emit (node:domain:489:12)
at emitErrorNT (node:internal/streams/destroy:151:8)
at emitErrorCloseNT (node:internal/streams/destroy:116:3)
at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:82:21) {
type: 'system',
errno: 'ETIMEDOUT',
code: 'ETIMEDOUT',
erroredSysCall: 'connect'

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.